# Get source of pasted text

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm deveploing a Vue application and wonder if it is possible to get the source of pasted text? E.g. if the pasted text comes from your own application, Word or Notepad?

I have tried the below but can't find anything about the source in the event.

```
<textarea @paste="onPaste"></textarea>

methods: {
    onPaste(event){
        console.log(event)
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+detect+source+of+clipboard+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Not a great duplicate, where the answer talks about a Windows API one can call. I know the OP mentions Word and Notepad, but nonetheless, let's keep at least within the realm of the same language/host platform.

Comment: [paste event](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-paste) - look at `e.clipboardData.types` - when copying, the source app may copy *multiple versions* by data type, eg plain text and rtf.  There's no distinction by app.

Comment: To determine if it's your *own* app, you could add an additional type when *copying* then check for that on paste, eg `e.clipboardData.setData('text/myapp', 'only my data allowed');` - most paste sources will just ignore this. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ugdx4296/  (you'll also need to handle "cut")

Comment: Thanks! That actually solves my problem. To bad someone marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: @freedomn-m  If the OP is lucky you can even tell the app.  eg, copy paste from VS code -> `["text/plain", "text/html", "application/vnd.code.copymetadata", "vscode-editor-data"]`

Comment: @freedomn-m   I'm marking as a re-open, as a snippet here instead of a jsfiddle link would be nice :)

Comment: @freedomn-m how do I keep formatting of copied html content in the copy event? I have tried ```document?.getSelection()?.toString()```.

Comment: TBH - this is why I didn't create an additional answer.  I couldn't (in the time I allotted, which wasn't very long) determine how to get what to copy in a nice wrapped up snippet.  All the samples are either a very basic "Hello World" or document.getSelection() - there also doesn't appear to be a `copied` event, only `about to copy` override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying @freedomn-m fiddle from comments here:

> To determine if it's your own app, you could add an additional type
> when copying then check for that on paste, eg
> `e.clipboardData.setData('text/myapp', 'only my data allowed');` - most
> paste sources will just ignore this.

Although not 100% showing what application, some examples on my machine, PopOS.

| Application | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Terminal(console) | ['text/plain'] |
| VsCode | ["text/plain", "text/html","application/vnd.code.copymetadata", "vscode-editor-data"] |
| Chrome / Browser | ["text/html", "text/plain"] |
| This snippet | ["text/html", "text/plain", "text/myapp"] |

Code originally from: [w3c clipboard event API](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-api) samples

```js
// https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-paste


// Overwrite what is being copied to the clipboard.
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  // e.clipboardData is initially empty, but we can set it to the
  // data that we want copied onto the clipboard.
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello, world!');
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', '<b>Hello, world!</b>');
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/myapp', "it's a secret");

  // This is necessary to prevent the current document selection from
  // being written to the clipboard.
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Overwrite what is being pasted onto the clipboard.
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  // e.clipboardData contains the data that is about to be pasted.
  console.log(e.clipboardData.types)
  if (e.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/html') > -1) {
    var oldData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
    var newData = '<b>Ha Ha!</b> ' + oldData;

    // Since we are canceling the paste operation, we need to manually
    // paste the data into the document.
    //pasteClipboardData(newData);

    // This is necessary to prevent the default paste action.
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='text'>
```

NB: you'll also need to handle "cut"

Comment: How do I keep formatting of copied html content in the copy event? I have tried document?.getSelection()?.toString() but that does not work.